# E0401: "Unable to import 'flask_sqlalchemy'"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have pip installed both Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy itself, and have checked that they are both up to date. However, when I try to run my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# from tables import Score, ScoreTable
import sqlite3 as sql

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
```

I continue to receive this error:

```
[pylint] E0401:Unable to import 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

Can anyone help with this? Maybe I am missing something simple.

Comment: From where are you running this? Which environment?

Comment: This is a warning from `pylint`, because it can't determine the location of sqlalchemy.  As @mad_ asks, are you running in an unusual environment (for example Google App Engine) where packages are installed in an unusual location?

Comment: I ran from a virtualenv (python) on my computer's terminal. Set up with "export FLASK_APP=app.py" and run with "flask run".

Comment: I wonder if the virtualenv was activated when pylint was called ...

Answer (score 11):

install flask-sqlalchemy out of the virtual environment first.
`$ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VScode use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).Then just change the python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I had these 2 errors:

```
Unable to import 'flask_sqlalchemy'
Unable to import 'flask_migrate'
```

The problem was this line in my models.py file:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I had a comma at end of the line and it caused me an hour of wasted time.

Answer (score 1):

## I had the same issue and found a simple solution to fix this.

Your code will search for libraries from the defined lib folder.

Kindly go to the lib folder where you have installed all the libraries and run the pip install Flask_SQLAlchemy.

### For example:

#### (venv) D:\python\Course_sample\MVC_code_model\code>

the above path is my code library if you install here it will not recognize.

#### (venv) D:\python\Course_sample\MVC_code_model\venv\Lib>

run the installation here the the Flask_SQLAlchemy will get imported into your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: **sqlalchemy** was not installed.

1. Use `pip list` or `pip freeze` to list all python modules
2. If the module is listed, I can't help you
3. If it is not listed, use `pip install SQLAlchemy` (on windows)
4. Close open the file and the error should be gone

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I had 2 different versions of python installed (3.6 and 3.7), all I did was uninstall python 3.7 and the Unable to import 'flask_sqlalchemy' error was not longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I have two versions of Python on my machine. 3.7.4 and 3.7.4 (conda) linked to Anaconda.
For some reasons, when on the conda version and using :

```
$ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

The installation does not go through, I had to switch to the 3.7.4 regular version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was using VS code and conda.
What solved it was to set my python interpreter in VS Code to the correct Conda env python.

In VS code press Ctrl-shift-P - select the correct python interpreter in the conda env.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error still in 2022 while creating app in env. I continuously installing it but still my Python interpreter doesn't recognised it.

The simplest solution for this is install SQLAlchemy outside the environment.
This will resolve the error and interpreter also recognise modules which are giving us errors so far.

If you are using VS Code then in select interpreter select your environment interpreter in this case you don't have to install it outside the environment just by using

> pip install flask-sqlalchemy

Hope this is usefull..

Answer (score -3):

I think you don't have the `wheel` package installed.

You should run this command to install it:

`pip install wheel`

This will call python's package manager, `pip`, to install `wheel`, which helps in installing most of `pip`'s packages.

Comment: please remember to wrap your answers between back ticks to make it more `readable`